# Function which can be extended to a $\mathcal{C}^k$ function for every $k\in\mathbb{N}$

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations

At the beginning of the PDE approximations course, the teacher notes for every open set $\Omega$ of $\mathbb{R}^p$, $C(\overline{\Omega}, \mathbb{R}^{q})$ the set of all applications $f : \Omega \to \mathbb{R}^{q}$ extendable to a $\mathcal{C}^{k}$ application defined on entire $\mathbb{R}^{p}$. (Which means that there exist a $\mathcal{C}^{k}$ application $g : \mathbb{R}^{p} \to \mathbb{R}^{q}$ such that $g = f$ on $\Omega$).

So I ask myself the following question :

If $\Omega$ is an open set of $\mathbb{R}^{p}$ and $f : \Omega \to \mathbb{R}^{q}$. We suppose that for every $k \in \mathbb{N}$ there existe a $\mathcal{C}^k$ application $g_k : \mathbb{R}^{p} \to \mathbb{R}^{q}$ such that $g_k = f$ on $\Omega$. Is it true that there exist a $\mathcal{C}^\infty$ application $g : \mathbb{R}^{p} \to \mathbb{R}^{q}$ such that $g =f$ on $\Omega$ ?